# How to solve an application shutting off after running it?

Tags: python

I created and excuted an application with Chat GPT, once I run the application and at a point it shuts off without giving any log info or error message. I tried to get the problem solved with chat GPT sence it was the one who coded the application, but it's not being solved.

## **Down below I included the calculator code with the setup code under it.**

```
# Function to calculate savings after taxes
def calculate_savings_after_taxes(income, expenses, federal_tax_rate, state_tax_rate):
    # Calculate federal and state taxes
    federal_tax = income * federal_tax_rate
    state_tax = income * state_tax_rate

    # Calculate savings after taxes
    savings_after_taxes = income - federal_tax - state_tax - expenses
    return savings_after_taxes

# Input your income and expenses
try:
    income = float(input("Enter your monthly income: $"))
    expenses = float(input("Enter your monthly expenses: $"))

    # Define federal and state tax rates as decimals (e.g., 0.20 for 20%)
    federal_tax_rate = 0.20  # Hypothetical federal tax rate
    state_tax_rate = 0.05   # Hypothetical Illinois state tax rate

    # Calculate savings after taxes
    savings_after_taxes = calculate_savings_after_taxes(income, expenses, federal_tax_rate, state_tax_rate)

    # Display results
    print("\nIncome: $", income)
    print("Expenses: $", expenses)
    print("Federal Tax: $", income * federal_tax_rate)
    print("State Tax (IL): $", income * state_tax_rate)
    print("Estimated Monthly Savings After Taxes: $", savings_after_taxes)

    if savings_after_taxes > 0:
        print("You can save money this month, after taxes! Great job.")
    elif savings_after_taxes == 0:
        print("You're breaking even, after taxes. Consider reviewing your expenses.")
    else:
        print("You're spending more than you earn, even after taxes. Consider adjusting your expenses.")

except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter valid numerical values for income and expenses.")
```

## ***Setup code:***

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name="Financial Calculator",
    version="1.0",
    description="Simple financial calculator",
    executables=[Executable("financial_calculator.py")]
)
```

Ok so I was trying Chat GPT to help me code and excute a python coded application, and the choice was a hypothetical financial calculator. I requested GPT to code it for me and give me a setup file to execute the application. So the calculator application is supposed to ask me my income, expenses, subtract hypothetical state and federal tax rates, and then give me an estemate with a little message telling me if I can save money or not this month. When I enter my income, expences and hit enter the excuted application shutts off. I tried the code in text editeors and it excutes the code normally. How can I solve the problem and run the application without it shutting off?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because publishing content generated by ChatGPT (not only answers) [isn't allowed currently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: `the ban applies to all content on Stack Overflow` indeed, we shouldn't be helping out here at all, as this is banned content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this statement at the bottom of the script such that it doesn't quit until a key is pressed.

```
input('Press any key to quit')
```

Comment: Since this question used ChatGPT, it's [not allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned); please don't encourage banned behavior.

Comment: pavi2410, thank you for the help. That was a solution!